# Deleting a Core Data object within a Realm Write Transaction Block?

Tags: ios, core-data, realm

I'm working on migrating a Core Data entity to Realm. There can be upwards of 2 million records in the entity, so I'm looking to do this as efficiently as possible.

The migration goes in batches of 10000 records or so, and the following is the code I'm using to do it:

```
/// We're in a loop
/// Get the 10000 records out of Core Data
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
// samples is an NSArray of NSManagedObjects
NSInteger numberOfSamples = samples.count;
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; i++)
{
    // WeightSample is an NSManagedObject
    WeightSample *sample = samples[i];

    //Diagnostic is an RLMObject
    Diagnostic *weightSample = [Diagnostic new];

    ///
    /// transfer data from WeightSample to Diagnostic
    ///

    [realm addObject:weightSample];

    // Remove the old sample from Core Data
    [context deleteObject:sample];
}
[realm commitWriteTransaction];

/// Start over at the top of the loop
```

- Am I going to run into any issues doing the `[context deleteObject:sample]` within the `beginWriteTransaction-commitWriteTransaction` block?

My assumption is 'No, but I'll be blocking longer', based on my cryptic [tweet @Realm](https://twitter.com/churowa/status/578938077411872768) and their reply.

- I can offload this to another thread, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar with Realm, but, in my case I found that just deleting all the core data sqlite files after the migration had finished, the fastest/most efficient. I'm assuming you don't need your core data store once migration is done, so, here's how I would do it.

```
/// We're in a loop
/// Get the 10000 records out of Core Data
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
// samples is an NSArray of NSManagedObjects
// WeightSample is an NSManagedObject
for (WeightSample *sample in samples)
{
    //Diagnostic is an RLMObject
    Diagnostic *weightSample = [Diagnostic new];

    ///
    /// transfer data from WeightSample to Diagnostic
    ///

    [realm addObject:weightSample];
}
[realm commitWriteTransaction];

/// Start over at the top of the loop

/// After all the data has been transferred to realm, delete all core-data sqlite files using NSFileManager API.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm a bit concerned about knowing *which* records have been converted though. The user could easily shut down the app at any point, and I wouldn't want to have to restart the migration every single time.

Comment: I suppose I should keep track of which records have been converted as I go. That way if the migration is killed, I can avoid converting records that have already been done.

Comment: Since we're dealing with a couple million records, the migration would take a while anyway. I'm guessing you would show the user some kind of activity indicator, or placeholder view controller while it's happening, might it be a good idea to inform the user in an alert, or in said placeholder view controller, that killing the app will cause the migration to restart? If duplicates is what you're worried about, I would have primary keys (that uniquely identify records) in realm, and use createOrUpate methods, I have found them to be pretty efficient.

Comment: On another note, I notice that you're not calling save: on your context, deletes you make don't propagate to the store until you call save: on your managed object context, so you might still have to restart the migration every single time if the app got killed. Quite frankly though, I found that doing any substantial number of core data saves within a realm write transaction slowed down realm considerably, and would avoid it unless there were no other options.